# local symfony 5 not working after changes on .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, https, symfony5

## Background

I tried to push each `http` to `https` and included this into `.htaccess`-file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

I understand now that this was a bad idea on my localhost (`dev.domainname.local`). So let's don't talk about it.

## Problem

I removed the above 4 lines again, but now each time, when I am calling `http://dev.domainname.local`, I get pushed to `https://dev.domainname.local`. And the website is NOT displayed.

And I cannot undo this behaviour. It must have something hardwired.

I tried to restart the local httpd (homebrew) and I cleared the cache from symfony (`./bin/console cache:clear`). But nothing helped.

Any idea? Many thanks!

Comment: This is most likely your _browser_ cache - redirects with status code 301 can get cached, and quite aggressively so. Clear your browser history, or test in a new private window.

Comment: WHOW!!!! many thanks... the easiest solutions are best in hiding themself ;-)